# Debian 10 blank screen after suspend (using lightdm xfce)

Tags: debian, sleep, xfce, blank-screen, lightdm

Every time I wake up the laptop after sleep I get a black screen. Pressing any key brings up the screen and shows the login screen, but logging in gets the screen black again and at that time the only thing that works is a shutdown through Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Notes:
I am running XFCE and lightdm
The problem happens when I close the lid of the laptop. It will go to suspend and then I wake it up by the power button.
The login screen on wakeup shouldn't be there. I had set it off in light-locker section of Power Manager

Only change I did from default install is in: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
[Seat:*]
pam-service=lightdm
pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
#session-wrapper=lightdm-session
autologin-user=deb
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=xfce
```

Comment: What is your swap partition size? Debian and Ubuntu need at least more than 4 GB swap partition for Hibernate or Suspend or Sleep to work properly. If you installed with default configuration it will create a Swap the same size of your actual RAM or a little less sized swap partition from your RAM. Recommended swap size is double of RAM. So if you have a laptop with less or equal to 4 GB RAM and installed default configuration, you will likely have the problem when you close laptop lid or choose Suspend from the power button.

Comment: @Wasif Seems to be 8G ( #free -m shows 8055 for Swap)

Comment: Hi, could you save the size of swap partition once OS is installed? Thanks & Best Regards Michael

Comment: Suspend to RAM does not require a swap partition. The "black screen on resume" is probably a bug. I have observed this with buster XFCE, as [have others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171996/blank-display-after-waking-up-using-external-monitor-as-primary-on-a-hp-laptop).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a problem with multiple graphics cards/devices which isn't unlikely in a laptop.
Here's the resources I've been finding searching for a solution to the same problem (though I run manjaro so I don't know how well they all will apply):

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3o3gxk/lightdm_after_suspend_i_login_black_screen/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1259339

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235419

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus#LightDM

The last link has a possible solution, though it's meant for a specific pair of cards and for arch it should apply broadly, use `xrandr --listproviders` to try and find out what card to use instead of 'NVIDIA-0'.
Good luck, I hope we both fix it!